# Cancel part of an order?

Tags: magento-1.7, edit-order

I've got an order with two items - and one is out of stock.

What's the proper way to cancel only one item?

If I invoice and ship one item, I end up with a hanging item. And if I hit the cancel button on the order, it still keeps the order total at the original amount and says the customer still owes money ... e.g.

Grand Total: $400
Total Paid: $200
Total Due: $200

But that total due should be zero, as the item's been cancelled. What should I be doing here?

(Magento seems to think that instead of cancelling, I should invoice and refund offline, but that seems ridiculous.)

Using Magento 1.7. Payment is via authorize.net ... And it's authorize only, rather than authorize & capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'solution' in the short term was to invoice the entire thing, and then refund for the item that wasn't in stock.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the order.
That will cancel the current order and you can create a new one with only the products you need.

Comment: When you do that, you have to input all the shipping info *and the credit card* information again - which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @SamC yep, that's the way it works, silly as you can always capture for less if you're merely dropping lines or reducing line quantities. Magento isn't your average accounting system in the backend, often it's less than average.

Comment: ayup. I now understand that my initial mistake was in expecting it to work intelligently.