# How to handle partial order cancellation in Magento?

Tags: edit-order, partial-payments

We are currently building an e-commerce website in Magento community edition (Version 1.9) and we specifically want "partial order cancellation" option, so it allows the customer to cancel the particular product from the order instead of canceling the entire order. We are also wondering if we can have this function in the front end (website) to explicitly allow the user to cancel particular product from the order instead of canceling the complete order. It would be really helpful if you could provide us with available extensions for this feature.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento). But I'll leave the question open because "find an extension" is not the only possible approach to it.

Comment: Also see this related question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/cancel-part-of-an-order?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not offer this feature for good reasons. Orders are required to not change as soon as they exist in the system and have an order number. Canceling an order partially would mean to either split it into two orders or to remove items from it.

If you think this is not a problem for you, I'd still advise you to consult a lawyer to be sure not to break laws of your country and the countries you ship to.

That's why, if you *edit* an order in the backend, the order actually gets canceled and a new one is created. To implement your requirement, I would suggest you to allow customers to edit their unprocessed orders in the customer account the same way as it is done in the backend (or look for an extension that does this).